# .resize() jQuery on mobile touch, uncheck a input field when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my website I want move a search form from desktop menu to mobile menu, for this I used thr `.resize()` function to check the screen width, then I use `appendto` and `prependto` to move the search form from desktop menu to mobile menu.

It works fine on my PC (desktop) , but when try on mobile it doesn't work correctly, when I click on search form I see the input become unchecked (not selected) after less 1 second clicked

this is the code :

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li id="form-search-mobile">
<div class="form-cerca">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="/">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="search">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</li>



<div id="primary-menu"></div>
<div class="entry-header"> </div>
```

you can view full code on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVzoqV

Comment: What do mean by "input became unchecked after less than 1 second clicked"?

Comment: @Larry Lane, when click on imput field you can write a text , but in this case after click when write on keyboard not write because the text imput field became unchecked(not selected), if you have a mobile phone you can check this

Comment: It works just fine on my android phone(samsung note4). I click on the box my keyboard comes up I type something and then it populates the input box.

Comment: @Larry Lane, i tried on galaxy s5 and and  galaxy tab, you have tried on chrome , firefox or default browser ?

Comment: I reached the link through the stack exchange app I will try it through chrome and see what happens.

Comment: @Larry Lane, have checked with different browser ?

Comment: It works on chrome with my note 4.

Comment: @Larry Lane: but the note 4 have this resolution "1440 x 2560 pixel" so call only function for  " > 741)" , maybe that's why you do not have the problem.

Comment: That's probably the reason